# How to include require plugin for a div popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few Jquery dialogs which does specific things.  I use jquery date-picker, time-picker etc in some of the dialogs, but I don't want to include the plugins in the common include page, or either the parent page (Where the div's are defined).

I want them to be included only on those specific divs.

I know this can be elegantly achieve using tiles, but I am not using tiles in this project.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add them conditionally

```
 <%  if(isCondtion)  {  %> 

                <tiles:insertAttribute name="plugin1" />

           <%  } else{  %>     
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="plugin2" />//other wise no plugin

           <%  }   %>
```

or if you don't want to use scriplets use JSTL tag libs

Comment: Thanks, but I've already mentioned that I know how to do that using tiles.